# Why doesn't this work? jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  musicList = new array()
  counter = 0;

  if($(".rA, .trA, .dA, .hA").length > 0)
  {

   /*$(".rA, .trA, .dA, .hA").each(function(e){*/
   $(".hA").each(function(e){

    $.post("/index/audio/ajax.track", { id: $(this).attr("rel") },
       function(data){




                                  /*THIS DOESN'NT WORK */
     musicList.push(data.file);
                                  /*THIS DOESN'NT WORK */
     alert(data.file);/*this words*/
       }, "json");

    counter++;

   });

   if(counter>0)
   {
    alert(counter);
   }
  }


});
```

I don't see anything wrong with the code but I have no idea why it won't work I just spent 3 hours trying to get it to work

/*edit*/
fixed it... the push was working the alert(counter) was a little dumb of me cause of ajax = async

thanks everybody

Comment: How do you see that the push doesn't work? Where are you accessing `musicList`? You are aware that the Ajax call happens asynchronously, and you can't expect the results to be there while you are processing the function?

Comment: What do you expect it to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: You should describe what you expect to happen and what actually does happen instead of saying "doesn't work." It's hard to help without knowing what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

- Declare the variables before you use them
- Always end statements with `;`.
- Ditch the first if-statement, it doesn't add anything
- You can use `$(f)` instead of `$(document).ready(f)` if you want
- You can use `[]` instead of `new Array()` if you want

The problem with your code is probably that the function you pass to `$.post` is being run **later on**, but control is returned right away, so when you get to the line starting with `if(counter>0)`, the function has never been executed. You can solve this by incrementing a variable each time you call $.post, when you get data back you decrement and check if all posts have returned and if so you do what you want to do. Example:

```
//...
var list = [];
var counter = 0;
$(".something").each(function() {
  counter++;
  $.post("http://www.example.com/", {foo = "bar"}, function(data) {
    list.push(data);
    counter--;
    if(counter === 0){
      alert(list.length);
    };
  })
});
//...
```